# Token list: Tokenization reverse puzzle: Did I solve it right? How to use \ShowTokens or \tl_analysis_show:n to prove my solution?

Tags: tex-core, latex3

I found this interesting article about tokens:

[Tokens in LuaTeX](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/35/05.pdf) from Hans Hagen.

> A macro definition converts to tokens as follows
>   **[B][A]**

Unfortunately, the macro definition is missing here.
( [pdf page 3 (document page 7) bottom right](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/35/05.pdf#page=3))

**Given token list:**

```
cmd           chr          id  namedef             
def             0     1114818  def
undefined_cs          1115536  Test  
mac_param      35    
other_char     49  1  
mac_param      35
other_char     50  2
left_brace    123
other_char     91  [
mac_param      35
other_char     50  2
other_char     93  ]
other_char     91  [
mac_param      35
other_char     49  1
other_char     93  ]
right_brace   125
spacer         32
undefined_cs          1115536   Test
left_brace    123
letter         65  A
right_brace   125
left_brace    123
letter         66  B
right_brace   125
```

Is this the correct macro definition?

`\def\Test #1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}`

Is it equivalent to this?

`\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test{A}{B}`

How can I prove these two statements?

✔ ted package: `\ShowTokens`

✔ expl3 package: `\tl_analysis_show:n`

✔ `\ifx` compare two token lists

❓ Joseph Wright "There are some good answers to show a **token breakdown**"

All approaches provide proof, but `\ShowTokens` seems safest for a beginner.

Comment: Yes, these are two possible inputs resulting in this token list (under "normal" catcodes). Given that they result in the same token list, they are equivalent.

Comment: Spaces after control words are ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the `\tl_analysis_show:n` proof (in a `latex` session with the `expl3` package loaded):

```
*\catcode`_=11

*\catcode`:=11

*\tl_analysis_show:n {\def\Test #1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}}
The token list contains the tokens:
>  \def (control sequence=\def)
>  \Test (control sequence=undefined)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  2 (the character 2)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  [ (the character [)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  2 (the character 2)
>  ] (the character ])
>  [ (the character [)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  ] (the character ])
>  } (end-group character })
>    (blank space  )
>  \Test (control sequence=undefined)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  A (the letter A)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  B (the letter B)
>  } (end-group character }).
<recently read> }

<*> ...w:n {\def\Test #1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}}

?

*\tl_analysis_show:n {\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test{A}{B}}
The token list contains the tokens:
>  \def (control sequence=\def)
>  \Test (control sequence=undefined)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  2 (the character 2)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  [ (the character [)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  2 (the character 2)
>  ] (the character ])
>  [ (the character [)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  ] (the character ])
>  } (end-group character })
>    (blank space  )
>  \Test (control sequence=undefined)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  A (the letter A)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  B (the letter B)
>  } (end-group character }).
<recently read> }

<*> ...how:n {\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test{A}{B}}
```

Both calls return the same output.

Comment: Perhaps do a 'better fix' of the form `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_eq:NN \ShowTokenAnalysis \tl_analysis_show:n `\ExplSyntaxOff`?

Answer (score 2):

These two:

```
\def\Test #1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}
\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test{A}{B}
```

represent the given token list, but the next one does not:

```
c:\>tex & dviout texput.dvi
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=tex)
**\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]}\Test{A}       {B}

*\bye
```

even if the visual result looks right:

[image]

Thanks to Marcel Krüger's hint here's  the token list generated with the ted package:

```
c:\>latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\RequirePackage{ted}
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

*\ShowTokens*{\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]}\Test{A}       {B}}
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ted/ted.sty)
--- Begin token decomposition of:
    \def \Test ##1##2{[##2][##1]}\Test {A} {B}
\def (control sequence=\def)
\Test (control sequence=undefined)
# (macro parameter character #)
1 (the character 1)
# (macro parameter character #)
2 (the character 2)
{ (begin-group character {)
[ (the character [)
# (macro parameter character #)
2 (the character 2)
] (the character ])
[ (the character [)
# (macro parameter character #)
1 (the character 1)
] (the character ])
} (end-group character })            <-----  missing space 
\Test (control sequence=undefined)   <-----  missing space
{ (begin-group character {)
A (the letter A)
} (end-group character })
  (blank space  )                    <-----  resulting from extra spaces               
{ (begin-group character {)
B (the letter B)
} (end-group character })
--- End token decomposition.
```

The macro `\ShowTokens` proves Marcel Krüger's statement.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger To the second part of your remark: There I was simply sloppy and denied the existence of the entry `spacer 32` in the token list. To the first part: Is there a primitive |  macro to inspect the token list? I will try in `hmode`.

Comment: The nicest way I can currently think of is `expl3`'s `\tl_analysis_show:n`, but you have to be careful because doing such experiments inside a `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff` block would lead to different output because of the catcode changes.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers to show a token breakdown, but you could answer the 'are they the same' question quickly using `\ifx`. All we need is to store the token lists in two macros. To avoid needing to worry about `#` doubling, I'm using `\unexpanded` inside an `\edef`

```
\edef\tempa{\unexpanded{\def\Test #1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}}}
\edef\tempb{\unexpanded{\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}}}
\ifx\tempa\tempb\TRUE\else\FALSE\fi
\bye
```

or without e-TeX

```
\toks0={\def\Test #1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}}
\edef\tempa{\the\toks0}
\toks0={\def\Test#1#2{[#2][#1]} \Test {A}{B}}
\edef\tempb{\the\toks0}
\ifx\tempa\tempb\TRUE\else\FALSE\fi
\bye
```

Both of these show `\TRUE`: the two macros are equal because the two token lists are equal.

Comment: Do you mind to link token breakdown answers? Perhaps there are techniques that display more information. Interesting the assignment of the token list to \toks0. Is this a register?